# Changing Friendly ID Default Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm trying to work out how to change the default column that Friendly Id generates the unique name to.

Currently, it requires the table to have a column called slug, but I need to generate a unique email address for an organisation, and 'slug' is not a correct identifier.

This is the code so far:

```
require 'friendly_id'

class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId

    friendly_id :name, :use => :email
end
```

which generates

```
NameError: uninitialized constant FriendlyId::Email
```

I think there is the ability to do a config and set the defaults through that, but that would change the slug column everywhere. I just need to change it for a specific model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this out

```
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged, slug_column: :email
```

Comment: Thanks RSB. That gives me a different result, now I'm getting: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column organisations.permalink does not exist

Comment: Okay. Fixed now. That last problem was a cut and paste error in the rake task I was using. I've marked this as the answer. Thanks RSB.